# how do i ensure persistence in rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

this is my signup code:

```
<%= render 'shared/errors',obj:@user %>

 <div class="row">
   <div class="col-xs-12">
     <%= form_for(@user, :html => {class: "form-horizontal", role: "form"}) do |f| %>

    <div class="form-group">
      <div class="control-label col-sm-2">
        <%= f.label :username %>
      </div>
      <div class="col-sm-8">
        <%= f.text_field :username, class: "form-control", placeholder: "Enter username", autofocus: true %>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
      <div class="control-label col-sm-2">
        <%= f.label :email %>
      </div>
      <div class="col-sm-8 ">
        <%= f.email_field :email, class: "form-control", placeholder: "Enter email", autofocus: true %>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
      <div class="control-label col-sm-2">
        <%= f.label :password %>
      </div>
      <div class="col-sm-8">
        <%= f.password_field :password,class: "form-control",placeholder: "Enter password" %>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
      <div class="control-label col-sm-2">
        <%= f.label :password_confirmation, 'Confirm' %>
      </div>
      <div class="col-sm-8">
        <%= f.password_field :password_confirmation,class: "form-control", autofocus:true %>
      </div>
    </div>

     <div class="form-group">
      <div class="control-label col-sm-2">
        <%= f.label :phone %>
      </div>
      <div class="col-sm-8 ">
        <%= f.text_field :phone, class: "form-control", placeholder: "Phone number", autofocus: true %>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
      <div class="control-label col-sm-2">
        <%= f.label :city %>
      </div>
      <div class="col-sm-8 ">
        <%= f.text_field :city, class: "form-control", placeholder: "Enter city", autofocus: true %>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
      <div class="control-label col-sm-2">
        <%= f.label :birthday %>
      </div>
      <div class="col-sm-8 ">
        <%= f.date_field :birthday, class: "form-control", placeholder: "Enter birthday", autofocus: true %>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
      <div class="col-sm-1 col-xs-offset-2">
        <%= f.radio_button :sex, "female" %>
      </div>
      <div class="control-label col-sm-1">
        <%= f.label :sex, "Female",  autofocus: true %>
      </div>

      <div class="col-sm-1">
        <%= f.radio_button :sex, "male" %>
      </div>
      <div class="control-label col-sm-1">
        <%= f.label :sex, "Male",  autofocus: true %>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
       <div class="col-sm-offset-2 col-sm-10">
         <%= f.submit(@user.new_record? ? "Sign up" : "Update account", class: "btn btn-primary btn-lg")%>
       </div>
    </div>
   <% end %>

 <div class="col-xs-4 col-xs-offset-4">
   [<%= link_to "Cancel request and return to articles listing", articles_path %>]
 </div>

   </div>
 </div>
```

This is my migration code:

```
class CreateUsers < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    create_table :users do |t|
      t.string :username
      t.string :email
      t.string :phone
      t.string :city
      t.date   :birthday
      t.string :sex

      t.timestamps
    end
  end
end
```

This is my users show code:

```
<br><h3 align="center">Welcome to <%= @user.username %>'s page</h3>
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-4 col-md-offset-4" align="center">
        <%= gravatar_for @user, size: 150 %>
    </div>
</div>
<br><div class="row align="center" ">
    Sex: <%= @user.sex %><br>
    Phone: <%= @user.phone %><br>
    City: <%= @user.city %><br>
    Birthday: <%= @user.birthday %> 
    <h4><%= @user.username %>'s articles</h4>
</div>
<div align="center">
    <%= will_paginate @user_articles %>
</div>
<%= render 'articles/article', obj: @user_articles %>
<div align="center">
    <%= will_paginate @user_articles %>
</div>
```

But the `sex`, `phone`, `city` and `birthday` are not showing in the users show page. How do I save this data to the database so that it will display?

This is my users controller:

```
class UsersController < ApplicationController
    before_action :set_user, only: [:edit, :update, :show]
    before_action :require_same_user, only: [:edit, :update, :destroy]
    before_action :require_admin, only: [:destroy]

    def index
        @users = User.paginate(page: params[:page], per_page: 5)
    end

    def new
        @user = User.new
    end

    def create
        @user = User.new(user_params)
        if @user.save
            session[:user_id] = @user.id
            flash[:success] = "Welcome to Loccaf #{@user.username}"
            redirect_to user_path(@user)
        else
            render 'new'    
        end 
    end

    def edit

    end

    def update

        if @user.update(user_params)
            flash[:success] = "Your account was updated successfully"
            redirect_to articles_path
        else
            render 'edit'
        end 
    end

    def show
        @user_articles = @user.articles.paginate(page: params[:page], per_page: 5)
    end

    def destroy
        @user = User.find(params[:id])
        @user.destroy
        flash[:danger] = "User and all articles created by user have been deleted"
        redirect_to users_path
    end

    private
        def user_params
            params.require(:user).permit(:username,:email,:password)
        end

        def set_user
            @user = User.find(params[:id])
        end
    def require_same_user
      if current_user != @user and !current_user.admin?
        flash[:danger] = "You can only edit your own articles"
        redirect_to root_path
      end 
    end 

    def require_admin
        if logged_in? and !current_user.admin?
            flash[:danger] = "Only admin users can perform this action"
            redirect_to root_path
        end 
    end
end
```

And this is my users model:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_many :articles, dependent: :destroy
    before_save {self.email = email.downcase}
    validates :username, presence: true, 
                uniqueness: {case_sensitive: false}, 
                length: {minimum:3, maximum: 25}
    VALID_EMAIL_REGEX = /\A[\w+\-.]+@[a-z\d\-]+\.[a-z]+\z/i
    validates :email, presence: true,length: {maximum: 105},    
                uniqueness: {case_sensitive: false},
                format: {with: VALID_EMAIL_REGEX}
    has_secure_password     
end
```

Comment: We need your controller code!

Comment: could you please share you Controller/Model code, may you missed Strong Parameters `params.require(:user).permit(:sex, :phone, :city, :bithday)`.

Comment: If you expect them to be, make them required in your model as well. EDIT: And look at your logs as you create the user, is there anything about those fields not being saved? Do you se the generated SQL INSERT?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You didn't whitelist those attributes in `user_params` method. The below code should work

```
def user_params
  params.require(:user).permit(:username, :email, :password, :sex, :phone, :city, :birthday)
end
```